# Как поменять иконки в блоке поделиться от Яндекса?

Tags: html, css, яндекс-диск

Недавно Яндекс открыл новый сервис Яндекс.Диск. В самом низу страницы есть блок "Поделиться". Это не что иное, как стандартный блок [Ya.share](http://api.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/concepts/share-button-ov.xml), но с измененными иконками. В самом API не указано, как добиться такого же эффекта (возможно, Яндекс сделает это в будущем).

Как воспроизвести?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А воспроизвести очень просто. Сначала добавить блок с классом `b-share-small-wrap`, в котором будет помещаться блок Яндекса

```
<div class="b-share-small-wrap">
    <div id="ya_share1"></div>
</div>
```

А затем добавить стили:

```
.b-share-wrap {
    text-align: center !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share-icon {
    background: url("http://disk.yandex.ru/_/Oqflxa-EpRmmYOHDl-QbrnkVrDU.png") no-repeat 0px 0px !important;
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share-icon {
    background: url("http://disk.yandex.ru/_/Oqflxa-EpRmmYOHDl-QbrnkVrDU.png") no-repeat 0px 0px !important;
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share-icon_vkontakte {
    background-position: -25px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share-icon_facebook {
    background-position: -50px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share-icon_twitter {
    background-position: -75px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share-icon_odnoklassniki {
    background-position: -100px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share-icon_lj {
    background-position: -125px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share-icon_vkontakte {
    background-position: -25px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share-icon_facebook {
    background-position: -50px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share-icon_twitter {
    background-position: -75px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share-icon_odnoklassniki {
    background-position: -100px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share-icon_lj {
    background-position: -125px 0px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share__handle {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    margin: 0px 8px !important;
    padding: 13px 10px 12px !important;
    border-radius: 3em !important;
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3em !important;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3em !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 3em !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share__handle:hover {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share {
    margin-top: -6px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share__handle {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27) !important;
    margin: 0px 3px !important;
    padding: 5px 2px 5px 3px !important;
    border-radius: 30px !important;
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px !important;
    -khtml-border-radius: 30px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share__handle:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15) !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_yaru {
    background-position: 0px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_yaru {
    background-position: 0px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_vkontakte {
    background-position: -25px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_vkontakte {
    background-position: -25px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_facebook {
    background-position: -50px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_facebook {
    background-position: -50px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_twitter {
    background-position: -75px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_twitter {
    background-position: -75px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_odnoklassniki {
    background-position: -100px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_odnoklassniki {
    background-position: -100px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_lj {
    background-position: -125px -21px !important;
}
.b-share-small-wrap .b-share__handle:hover .b-share-icon_lj {
    background-position: -125px -21px !important;
}
```

P.S. Может кому-то пригодиться.