# Как изменить иконки в блоке поделиться от Яндекс?

Tags: html, css, ya-share2

Каким образом изменить/заменить иконки в блоке [поделиться](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/) от Яндекс?
В API об этом не сказано.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/103559/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0 - тут написано... возможно что-то поменялось с 2012 года

Answer (score 5):

Например заменить фон либо общий, либо для каждой иконки:

```js
new Ya.share({
  element: 'share',
  elementStyle: {
    'type': 'none',
    'quickServices': ['vkontakte', 'facebook', 'twitter']
  },
  link: document.location.href,
  title: document.title
});
```

```css
#share .b-share-icon_vkontakte,
#share .b-share-icon_facebook,
#share .b-share-icon_twitter {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: transparent;
}

#share .b-share-icon_vkontakte {
    background: url(http://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2013/96/iconmonstr-vk-1.png) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}

#share .b-share-icon_facebook {
    background: url(http://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2012/96/iconmonstr-facebook-1.png) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}

#share .b-share-icon_twitter {
    background: url(http://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2012/96/iconmonstr-twitter-1.png) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://yandex.st/share/share.js"></script>

    <div id="share"></div>
```

Еще вариант с `:before` на примере иконок font-awesome:

```js
new Ya.share({
  element: 'share',
  elementStyle: {
    'type': 'none',
    'quickServices': ['vkontakte', 'facebook', 'twitter']
  },
  link: document.location.href,
  title: document.title
});
```

```css
#share {
  background: transparent;
}

#share [class*="b-share-icon_"] {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#share [class*="b-share-icon_"]:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 2rem/2rem FontAwesome;
  color: #333;
}


#share .b-share-icon_vkontakte:before {
    content: '\f189';
}

#share .b-share-icon_facebook:before {
    content: "\f09a";
}

#share .b-share-icon_twitter:before {
   content: "\f099";
}


#share [class*="b-share-icon_"]:hover:before {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" />
  
<script src="http://yandex.st/share/share.js"></script>

    <div id="share"></div>
```